# How to check if CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS enable?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, configuration

I have to program a realtime application on Linux, but don't know whether the standard installation of Ubuntu has `CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS` enabled. How can I check this?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 64bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu ships the kernel configuration in `/boot/config-$version` (in the same package as the kernel image `/boot/vmlinuz-$version`). You can check this file on a live system, or you can download it from [the Ubuntu website](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image). There are several images to choose from; the default under amd64 is [`-generic`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/linux-image-2.6.38-8-generic), and you can download the binary package and extract the file `/boot/config-*`. The simplest way to open a Debian package if you're not running a dpkg-based distribution is to convert it with [alien](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/alien/).

By the way, the answer is yes under 10.04/-generic/amd64 which I happened to have available while writing this answer.

Several other distributions ship a `/boot/config-*` file. Others make the kernel configuration available in `/proc/config` or something similar, so that it's easy to see on a live system but doesn't appear in the binary package. In that case, if you don't have a live system, you need to check the source package.

Comment: Actually, probably the simplest way to look inside a Debian package and extract a file is to use Midnight Commander. Since a Debian package is just an `ar` archive, one can also use `ar x packagename`, which decomposes into `control.tar.gz` and `data.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use _SC_TIMERS and clock_getres() etc. instead of wondering how the kernel specifically was configured.

Answer (score 0):

Many kernels have a copy of their config files that is exposed through the `proc` file system:

```
zcat /proc/config |
    grep CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS
```

If not, there is a tool in the kernel source to to extract it from the kernel file itself: (Use your path to the kernel source directory and kernel file to extract from.)

```
/usr/src/linux/scripts/extract-ikconfig /boot/vmlinuz |
    grep CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS
```

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't include a `/proc/config` patch. Like Debian, it ships `config-$version` alongside `vmlinuz-$version`.